# Android Studio icon is missing when I install my app

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I have developed an app everything was working ok but when I sent to Google Play Store and I tried to install the app from store, the icon doesn't show in the screen. Now when I run it from emulator the icon doesn't show again.

This is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.myAppName"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".luces"
        android:exported="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tried to reupload the icon using File > New Image Asset but it didn't worked